# UIViewController to know if it got pushed or popped?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a main UITableView, when cell is pressed it goes to another UITableView and when a cell is pressed there it goes to a DetailView of that cell.

I want the middle UITableView to behave differently depending on if the detailView got popped or the UITableView itself got pushed. If the view got pushed on from the main table I want to scroll to the top, if it is shown after a DetailView got popped I want it to stay at the same position.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could call a scrollToTop method on the DetailViewController after you have pushed it to the navigationController.

Something like that:

```
if (!detailViewController) {
    detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController scrollToTop];
// or use the tableView directly: 
// [detailViewController.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't even know you could scroll before the view was "visible".

Answer (score 1):

In your Middle View Controller, examine which view is next-to-display directly from the UINavigationController stack:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self.navigationController.topViewController isEqual:(UITableViewController *)tvcDetailView]) {
        // Detail view has been pushed onto the UINavigationController stack
    }
    else {
        // Middle view has been popped from the UINavigationController stack
    }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't perfect for this problem since it didn't account for first launch of the view (should be scrolled then as well. But it actually worked great with another problem I had, so thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Create a BOOL `@property` on your middle UIViewController property called `wasPushed` or something similar, and when you initialise it from UIViewController 1, set the property on the new instance, push it onto the nav stack and you can then use your property in your middle view controller's `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWill/DidAppear` methods.

As soon as you've used it, set it back to FALSE or NO (or whatever) and when you end up coming back to it due to popping off your 3rd view controller you'll have it as FALSE/NO in your `loadView`, `viewDidLoad` etc.. methods.

Comment: nothe that `viewDidLoad`is not getting called when you popped your 3rd view controller

Comment: you'd get `viewDidLoad` if you hit a memory warning or the viewController's view was thrown away while you were deeper in the stack.

Comment: hm didnt know that, thx for the hint. Is there a rule or some definition about when the viewController's view is thrown away?

Comment: Checkout the `viewDidUnload` description in the UIViewController documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html